# Six couples sit around a circular

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can six couples sit around a circular table: No man sits next to a man. No man sits next to his wife.

Attempt: i would've just said 5! x 4! = 2880 from the formula for circular permutations if we fix the women say, on alternate seats, then their husbands can't sit on either side of them

Comment: Are we to assume all heterosexual married couples? Treating couples as single entities would mean every man is next to his wife, which must not happen.

Comment: @aschepler yes, Are we to assume all heterosexual

Comment: Your phrasing of the question is ambiguous. What does “two men not sitting together mean”? Any two men? Or a specific set of $2$ men out of the $6$ men in the circle i.e. the other $4$ can be together? Also, what does “not one man sitting with his wife” mean? The English needs to be a little clearer here.

Comment: @LockyPauk Is the problem correctly stated now? It seems rather complicated to solve. I got  11520 with the help of a small program.  What is the source of the problem?

Comment: As a hint, try to figure out what you can conclude from the condition that no man is sitting next to each other. Then try to fit in the spouses.

Comment: Also, are two seatings the same if one can be made from a rotation of the other?

Comment: @LockyPauk think my program has an error and the number is not correct. The correct number seems to be 9600.

Comment: What does try to fit the spouses mean? do you have a formula for that?

Comment: @miracle173 The answer is 9600. How did you do it?

Comment: @aschepler Why should we assume that they are married?

Comment: @miracle173 Good question. If we have six heterosexual unmarried couples, then it's trivially true that no man sits next to his wife (and the answer would be $2(6!)^2$, or $(6!)(5!)$ if rotations are equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

I messed with this for awhile and came up with a pattern (0,0,2,12,312,9600,...) that matches up with this pattern:

https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C0%2C2%2C12%2C312%2C9600&sort=&language=english&go=Search

The pattern's description pretty much matches the question, so that makes sense...

The method I used to come up with this pattern was to work with smaller numbers of couples.  With only one or two couples, there is no way for couples not end up seated together, thus the first two zeroes.

For 3 couples, you first seat the wives in (3-1)!=2!=2 ways.  Then the husbands each only have one choice of seat in order not to sit with their wives.  2*1=2.

For 4 couples, you seat the wives in (4-1)=3!=6 ways.  Then upon writing out the ways that the husbands can be seated, you find that they only have 2 viable options for seating arrangements.  Thus 6*2=12.

5 couples gets fairly tedious for seating the husbands (there are 120 potential arrangements that you have to consider), but there end up 13 seatings for the husbands that work, meaning 13*24=312 seatings for the couples.

Since brute forcing 5 couples was so tedious, obviously 6+ couples would be even worse so I ended up writing a script in Matlab to evaluate lists of all possible permutations of a given size and fed it the relevant permutation lists.  That fleshed out the next several values which I put together and ran through a search of OEIS to find the above link.

The seating arrangements for the husbands seems to me like a more complicated variation of a derangement, which I suppose explains why no graceful counting method presents itself...

Anyway, long story short, the answer is 9,600 seating arrangements.

Comment: I tried to edit my question. Is it clearer?

Comment: Clearer, but far more complicated to solve!

Answer (score 1):

I used a very laborious way to calculate these value. At the end of my post you see some references to articles that may be useful.

We have $12$ seats around the table and  on every second place is occupied by a man and every second seat is occupied by a woman. We do not differentiate between two seat occupancies that can be converted into one another by rotation.
We number the men from $0$ to $5$ and the women from $0$ to $5$
Assume that the men's seats are occupied by $0,1,2,3,4,5$ in this order. The wife of $0$ can not sit between $0$ and $1$, but it can sit between $1$ and $2$. Let's list all the possible positions where $0$'s wife sits between $1$ and $2$. These are shown by the following table. The first line shows the position of the men. The following line show all possible positions of the women.

Table 1

```
0   1   2   3   4   5    0
  2   0   1   5   3   4   
  5   0   1   2   3   4   
  3   0   1   5   2   4   
  4   0   1   5   2   3   
  4   0   1   5   3   2   
  2   0   5   1   3   4   
  3   0   5   1   2   4   
  4   0   5   1   2   3   
  5   0   4   1   2   3   
  4   0   5   1   3   2   
  5   0   4   1   3   2   
  2   0   4   5   1   3   
  3   0   5   2   1   4   
  4   0   5   2   1   3   
  5   0   4   2   1   3   
  3   0   4   5   1   2   
  2   0   4   5   3   1   
  4   0   5   2   3   1   
  5   0   4   2   3   1   
  3   0   4   5   2   1
```

***How can we construct this table?***

We seat woman $0,1,2,3,4,5$ in this order were each woman is placed in the most left position that wasn't already tried before. So the most left position that we can place $0$ is between $1$ and $2$, because it is not allowed to be placed between $0$ and $1$.

```
0   1   2   3   4   5    0
      0
```

The woman $1$ can also not be placed between man $0$ an $1$ so it will be placed between man $2$ and $3$.

```
0   1   2   3   4   5    0
      0   1
```

The leftmost position where we can place $2$ is between $0$ and $1$. If we continue this process we will end up with

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   0
  2   0   1   5   3   4
```

This is the first line of our table

To find a line following a line of the table we do similar procedure. So to find the next line after the eleventh line

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   0
  5   0   4   1   3   2
```

we consider the following

***How can be use this table to calculate the number of women's positions?***
The last number we place on this line was $5$. We remove it but cannot place it on a different position because only this position is free. So re remove $4$. It cannot be place on a more right position. The left positions were already tried in previous steps before this line. So we remove $3$ and $2$, too. Finally we have to remove $1$. $1$ can be in the next right position now.

```
 0   1   2   3   4   5   0
       0           1
```

Now we place $2$ and $3$ in the most left position:

```
 0   1   2   3   4   5   0
   2   0           1   3
```

and fill up with $4$ and $5$ and get:

```
 0   1   2   3   4   5   0
   2   0   4   5   1   3
```

After the last line of the table

```
 0   1   2   3   4   5   0
  3   0   4   5   2   1
```

the next line  will be a line with the woman 0 between 2 and 3, so we stop here.

There is another notaiton that we can use to represent the positions of the women. in the i-th positions we note the number of seats after  the seat of the women i and the seat after man i. So if they are seated like

```
 0   1   2   3   4   5   0
   2   0   4   5   1   3
```

we have `1 3 4 2 4 4`.
Woman $$0 is place one seat after the seat next to men $0$, women $1$ is place $3$ seats after teh seat next to man $1$ and so on. With 'next' we mean always the  direction of the seats of the men `0-1-2-3-4-5-0`. We call these number of seats differences $d_i$
So we get the tuple $(d_1, d_2, d_3, d_4, d_5, d_6)$ of differences. From each such tuple we can generate another tuple of differences by rotating the tuple:

$$(d_1, d_2, d_3, d_4, d_5, d_6)\\
(d_2, d_3, d_4, d_5, d_6, d_1)\\
(d_3, d_4, d_5, d_6, d_1, d_2)\\
(d_4, d_5, d_6, d_1, d_2, d_3)\\
(d_5, d_6, d_1, d_2, d_3, d_4)\\
(d_6, d_1, d_2, d_3, d_4, d_5)\\
$$

These represent all valid permutations.

Also the following tuples represent valid permutations
$$(5-d_6, 5-d_5, 5-d_4, 5-d_3, 5-d_2, 5-d_1)\\
(5-d_5, 5-d_4, 5-d_3, 5-d_2, 5-d_1, 5-d_6, )\\
(5-d_4, 5-d_3, 5-d_2, 5-d_1, 5-d_6, 5-d_5, )\\
(5-d_3, 5-d_2, 5-d_1, 5-d_6, 5-d_5, 5-d_4, )\\
(5-d_2, 5-d_1, 5-d_6, 5-d_5, 5-d_4, 5-d_3, )\\
(5-d_1, 5-d_6, 5-d_5, 5-d_4, 5-d_3, 5-d_2, )\\
$$

These operations define an equivalenc relation on the se of all valid differences. A class contains at most $12$ tuples of differences.
So for our tuple

```
1 3 4 2 4 4
```

we get

```
1 3 4 2 4 4 
3 4 2 4 4 1 
4 2 4 4 1 3 
2 4 4 1 3 4 
4 4 1 3 4 2 
4 1 3 4 2 4
```

by the first six operations and

```
4 2 1 3 1 1 
2 1 3 1 1 4 
1 3 1 1 4 2 
3 1 1 4 2 1 
1 1 4 2 1 3 
1 4 2 1 3 1
```

So the class of the tuple $(1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4)$ contains of these $12$ tuples.With regards to lexicographic order $(1,1,4,2,1,3)$ is the minimum of this set.

For all tuples of Table 1 we can replace the tuple by this minimum of the corresponding class of differences. If we replace
we get the following set of tuples (we remove tuples that appear more than once)

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 2 2 2 4
1 1 2 3 1 4
1 1 3 1 2 4
1 1 4 1 1 4
1 2 2 2 2 3
1 2 2 3 1 3
1 2 3 1 2 3
1 3 1 3 1 3
```

From these eight difference tuples we can generate all difference tuples that contain either $1$ or $4$ by using the $12$ operations.

All other valid difference tuples contain only the differences $2$ or $3$.

If the only differences are $2$ or $3$ then the following table shows the men and the seats with the women that can be place there

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   0
 34  45  50  01  12  23
```

From this we see that only

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   0
  3   4   5   0   1   2
  4   5   0   1   2   3
```

are valid positions and the corresponding difference tuples are

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3 3
```

wich are in the same class

So the classes of all tuples are

```
1 1 1 1 1 1    1 * 2     2
1 1 2 2 2 4    6 * 2    12
1 1 2 3 1 4    6 * 2    12
1 1 3 1 2 4    6 * 2    12
1 1 4 1 1 4    3 * 2     6
1 2 2 2 2 3    6 * 2    12
1 2 2 3 1 3    6 * 2    12
1 2 3 1 2 3    3 * 2     6
1 3 1 3 1 3    2 * 2     4
2 2 2 2 2 2    1 * 2     2
```

The first number of the `a*b` column is the number of different tuples that are generated by the tuples of the first six transformations on the tuple  (rotation). This must be multiplied by $2$ because of the other $6$ transformation
The final column contains the result of this product, which is the number of elements in the class.
If we sum up we get $80$ differences and therefore $80$ valid positions for the women.
The seat where the men $0$ is sitting is always the first position in our diagrams. The remaining $5$ men can be placed in $5!$ ways, So all in all we have $80\cdot 5!=9600$ possible positions.

***How to Find More Information***

I checked my results by running a simple program that checks all the $6!$ possible positions for the women and found out that $80$ are admissible.

My program also checked the number of admissible positions for $4$ to $8$ women and gets the results $2, 13, 80, 579, 4738$

When you search the internet for the sequence `2,13,80,579,4738` you probably will find

[A000179 from The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A000179) and find out that these numbers are called *Menage Numbers* and where

> `a(n) = number of permutations s of [0, ..., n-1] such that s(i) != i and  s(i) != i+1 (mod n) for all i.`

And if you search  for Menage numbers you will probably fine the [Wikipedia article about Menage-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_problem) you will find the number $115200=2\cdot 80 \cdot6!$, so there they count different placement that can be achieved by rotating the table as different.

***Some Numbers and Formulae from the Wikipedia Article***

The Menage Numbers $A(n)$, this is the number of the ways the $n$ women can be placed between the $n$ men if the men are already seated, for $n=3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ are

$$1, 2, 13, 80, 579, 4738, 43387, 439792$$

Formulas are

$$A(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac {2 n}{2n-k}{{2n-k}\choose k} (n-k)!$$

$$A(n)=nA(n-1)+\frac n{n-2}A(n-2)+\frac{4(-1)^{n-1}}{n-2}$$

$$A(n)=nA(n-1)+2A(n-2)-(n-4)A(n-3)-A(n-4)$$